# Parsing all input tags of a page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse all the input tags of (type = text) in the page : http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx

As you can see in the above url there are 2 forms.

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request
import requests
import webbrowser
import urllib.parse

url = "http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx"

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

form = soup.find('form')
inputs = form.find('input', type='text').get('name')
print(inputs)
```

When I run the above code I get the name attribute of only the first form. Even if I iterate using the following :

```
for elements in inputs:
   print(elements.get('name'))
```

I get the name attribute of only the first form. How to parse all the forms and all the inputs of any page regardless of the no. of forms in a page?

If I use **soup.find_all('form')** instead of find(form) I get an error. What could be wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the `input` elements from the page using code like this.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx'
>>> page = requests.get(url).text
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> inputs = soup.findAll('input', attrs={'type': 'text'})
>>> len(inputs)
3
>>> for input in inputs:
...     input.attrs['name']
... 
'txtSearch'
'name'
'email_addr'
```

However, I expect that you want all of the `input` element capable of receiving string input that are inside the form whether they have been properly labelled as to type or not. This part of the code is quite inconsistent (not all `input` elements have a `type` for instance) and it seems to me it might be necessary to parse out rows of the table and then select from them.

```
>>> form = soup.find('form', attrs={'name': 'cmt'})
>>> table = form.find('table')
>>> leftColumns = table.findAll('td', attrs={'align': 'right'})
>>> for column in leftColumns[1:-1]:
...     column.findNextSibling().findChild()
... 
<input name="name" size="25" type="text" value=" "/>
<input name="email_addr" size="25" type="text"/>
<input name="subject" size="25"/>
```

The use of `etree` might be easier because you can use xpath expressions. In this case I noticed that the desired `input` elements all had non-empty `size` attributes.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(page, parser=parser)
>>> inputs = tree.xpath('.//form[@name="cmt"]//input[@size and string-length(@size)]')
>>> len(inputs)
3
>>> for input in inputs:
...     input.attrib
...     
{'value': ' ', 'name': 'name', 'size': '25', 'type': 'text'}
{'name': 'email_addr', 'size': '25', 'type': 'text'}
{'name': 'subject', 'size': '25'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your code as:

```
import bs4 as bs 
import urllib.request
import requests
import webbrowser
import urllib.parse

url = "http://demo.testfire.net/feedback.aspx"

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,"html.parser")

form = soup.findAll('form')
for i in form:
   inputs = i.find('input').get('name')
   print(inputs)
```